# Java: Best way to display multiple buffered images in a horizontal orientation(e.g. film reel)

Tags: java, panel, bufferedimage

I have a doubly linked list that's storing a bufferedimage in each node. I can easily retrieve all the buffered images by creating an iterator and iterating through list. I want to display each node horizontally one after the other in some sort of a panel. This would be similar to a film reel where frames are linked one after the other. I am not quite sure on how to go about doing so and what I should look into. I am not asking for any specific code I just need some pointing in the right direction.

Comment: Do you understand what's required to display just one image?

Comment: Yes, I have been able to display each BufferedImage one after the other by creating an ImageIcon out of each node and displaying them on a JLabel. The displaying of each ImageIcon on the JLabel is adjustable via a JSlider so that you can speed up the animation or slow it down.

Answer (score 0):

Use a JList. You can add Icons to the ListModel and display the list horizontally in a scroll pane.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Lists](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for the response. This seems like what I was looking for and I think that it will work.